# Phonegap app uses high RAM because filereader() and change loaded pics to white instead because of memory usage

Tags: cordova, ram, filereader

I have an Phonegap application that I'm using it as a photo album.
I'm reading jpg files with FileReader function, about 1,000 pics in size of 400pxx350px.
Once opening the app it loads all pics together and it takes about 1.5 minutes.
The ram usage(cache) of the app become to be about 350MB.
After using the app for a while and navigating between pics, the RAM usage increase to about 450-500MB, and then some pics that already loaded correctly become white instead of the pic and if using the app more it crashes sometimes.
If closing the app and restart it it starting again with 350MB usage of cache RAM and again can use it couple of hours until the RAM usage increase again and some pics turned to white again.

How can I reduce the RAM usage? Or maybe there is better way to load the pics?
Thanks,
Ofir.

Answer (score 0):

1000 images of those dimensions is a significant amount of data so will take a significant amount of RAM. Do you really need all 1000 to be in memory at the same time? Without knowing the user interface layout and use case requirements for your app I'm just speculating, but could you not, for example, load each image on demand asynchronously as it needs to be displayed? Or if the delay in reading the image from the file system creates an unacceptable delay in displaying it, you could pre-load just some of the images, for example if they are in a sequence, then just have a couple in memory either side of the currently displayed image.